# how to remove duplicated tweets in R?

Tags: r, using

I am doing a text mining on tweets
I have a problem with the duplicate tweets, like this:

"aeCERT: aeCERT provides an ongoing Information Security Awareness Program for Constituents, Law enforcement, Academic sector and Public."

"Salim_aeCERT: aeCERT provides an ongoing Information Security Awareness Program for Constituents, Law enforcement, Academic sector and Public."

I got the same tweets for two different account, how I could eliminate one from my dataset? I have tried this code but the duplicated tweets still appear:

```
tweets1.df <- do.call("rbind", lapply(tweets, as.data.frame))
tweets2.df <- tweets1.df[duplicated(tweets1.df ) == FALSE,] 
dim(tweets2.df)
```

How can I remove duplicate tweets from different accounts?

Comment: you could remove everything before the colon (-> regex, gsub, substr, etc.) and than compare the strings or you could use approximate string matching (-> agrep()).

Answer (score 5):

Extract the texts from the tweets and then use `duplicated` to remove actual duplicates.

```
tweets = searchTwitter('aeCERT: aeCERT' , n=100, cainfo = "cacert.pem")
texts <- sapply( unlist( tweets ) , function(x) `$`( x , "text" ) )
length(texts)
#[1] 100
texts[87:91]
#[1] "You should always update your Operating System  to reduce and eliminate vulnerabilities  http://t.co/l0sdv0k304"                            
#[2] "We are today at Dubai Electricity and Water Authority (DEWA) in Dubai conducting information security awareness workshop by Eng. Khalifa..."
#[3] "We are today at Dubai Electricity and Water Authority (DEWA) in Dubai conducting information security awareness workshop by Eng. Khalifa..."
#[4] "صباح الخير لجميع المغردين ..متواجدين اليوم في هيئة كهرباء ومياه دبي  لعقد ورش التوعية الأمنية الالكترونية يقدمها المهندس خليفة الشامسي"     
#[5] "صباح الخير لجميع المغردين ..متواجدين اليوم في هيئة كهرباء ومياه دبي  لعقد ورش التوعية الأمنية الالكترونية يقدمها المهندس خليفة الشامسي"

unq.texts <- texts[ ! duplicated( texts ) ]
length(unq.texts)
#[1] 82
unq.texts[71:74]
#[1] "You should always update your Operating System  to reduce and eliminate vulnerabilities  http://t.co/l0sdv0k304"                             
#[2] "We are today at Dubai Electricity and Water Authority (DEWA) in Dubai conducting information security awareness workshop by Eng. Khalifa..." 
#[3] "صباح الخير لجميع المغردين ..متواجدين اليوم في هيئة كهرباء ومياه دبي  لعقد ورش التوعية الأمنية الالكترونية يقدمها المهندس خليفة الشامسي"      
#[4] "RT @Salim_aeCERT: لا تستجب للمكالمات الهاتفية التي تخبرك بأنك ربحت جوائز قيمة ومبالغ مالية، فقد تكون ضحية للاحتيال #aecert http://t.co/HTK5…"
```

Be aware that even a one character change in the text of the tweet means a tweet will not be detected as a duplicate (relevant in the case where someone retweets and adds a link through a different link shortener for instance).

You could also do something like

```
sapply( unlist( tweets ) , function(x) length(`$`( x , "replyToUID" ) ) > 0 )
```

To get a logical vectorof all tweets that are replies to someone elses tweet, or

```
sapply( unlist( tweets ) , function(x) length(`$`( x , "retweeted" ) ) > 0 )
```

to get a logical vector of tweets that are retweets (but I'm not sure this is reliable as no tweets were retweets in my sample). Other applicable names and methods can be found using (for instance):

```
str(tweets[[1]])
Reference class 'status' [package "twitteR"] with 14 fields
 $ text        : chr "<U+062A><U+0639><U+0644><U+0645> <U+0627><U+0644><U+0645><U+0632><U+064A><U+062F> <U+0639><U+0646>  <U+062A><U+062D><U+062F><U+"| __truncated__
 $ favorited   : logi FALSE
 $ replyToSN   : chr(0) 
 $ created     : POSIXct[1:1], format: "2013-06-04 08:02:24"
 $ truncated   : logi FALSE
 $ replyToSID  : chr(0) 
 $ id          : chr "341827259352641536"
 $ replyToUID  : chr(0) 
 $ statusSource: chr "<a href=\"http://www.hootsuite.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">HootSuite</a>"
 $ screenName  : chr "Salim_aeCERT"
 $ retweetCount: num 1
 $ retweeted   : logi FALSE
 $ longitude   : chr(0) 
 $ latitude    : chr(0)
```

Comment: re: "Be aware that even a one character change in the text of the tweet means a tweet will not be detected as a duplicate" you may note that the package [RecordLinkage](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RecordLinkage/index.html) specifically the RLBigDataDedup() can assist.

Comment: @JackRyan Thanks for the pointer. I will check it out (not for this application, but related)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like:

```
tweets2.df <- unique(sapply(tweets1.df$tweets, FUN = function(tmp)
    sub(regmatches(tmp,regexpr("^[[:alnum:]*|[:punct:]*]*[:] ",tmp))[[1]],"",tmp)
))
```

EDIT (without unnecessary `sapply`):

```
unique(gsub(regmatches(tweets,regexpr("^[[:alnum:]*|[:punct:]*]*[:] ",tweets))[[1]],"",tweets))
```

Comment: thanks guys alot , your help is very appreciated..I have solved the problem by: tweets2.df <- tweets1.df [!duplicated(tweets1.df$text),]

Comment: You should post that comment as an answer and then delete the comment.